# Powershell: The right commandline to set a ListTemplate via powershell

Tags: list, powershell, ms-word

I have an issue with a bit of code to create a word document, fill this with some lines of text, creating a list (numbering, 1., 1.1, 1.1.1, etc) and then creating an index. (`$i` is part of a for loop)

This works amazingly well when I just use the following line of code:

```
$paragraphs[0].Item($i).range.ListFormat.ApplyNumberDefault(1)
```

The output is then:

> *1., a., i.*

For some reason it defaults to 'single level' lists if I put down:

```
$paragraphs[0].Item($i).range.ListFormat.ApplyNumberDefault(0)
```

Resulting in the output:

> 1., 2., 3.

However, using the below code obviously doesn't work, because I need a `ListTemplate` object to apply to the format, but I can't find any specific way to create that object in Powershell. There's some VBA examples, but I seem incapable of translating this to Powershell.

```
$paragraphs[0].Item($i).range.ListFormat.ApplyListTemplate('wdStyleListBullet2')
```

The intended end-result has to be 1., 1.1., 1.1.1. ... 
(Obviously the bullet2 style is just an example, the question is how do I create the ListTemplate object in Powershell).

```
#Function to create a or multiple paragraphs, to prevent absurd paragraph clutter
function CreateParagraph($Selection, $count)

{
    for ($i = 0;$i -lt $count;$i++){
    $Selection.TypeParagraph()
    }
}

#Function to create numbered lists based on a selected range of paragraphs
function NumberParagraphs($Selection, $paragraphs, $countstart, $countend, $indent)

{
    $x = $false
    $template = $word.ListGalleries[[Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdListGalleryType]::WdBuiltinStyle].ListTemplates(2)
    $template

    for ($i = $countstart;$i -le $countend;$i++)

    {  
        if (($paragraphs[0].Item($i).range.text -ne $null) -and ($paragraphs[0].Item($i).range.text  -ne "") -and ($paragraphs[0].Item($i).range.text.length -gt 1))

        {
#Set the listtemplate style here
            #$paragraphs[0].Item($i).range.ListFormat.ApplyNumberDefault(1)
            $paragraphs[0].Item($i).range.ListFormat.ApplyListTemplate($template)
        }
        if ($x -eq $false)
        {
            $indent
            if ($indent -eq -1)

            {
                $paragraphs[0].Item($i).range.ListFormat.ListLevelNumber = 1
            }
            else
            {
                $paragraphs[0].Item($i).range.ListFormat.ListLevelNumber = $indent
            }
        }
        $x = $true
    }
}

#create Word object, create a new Word document
$Word = New-Object -ComObject Word.Application
$Word.Visible = $True
$Document = $Word.Documents.Add()
$Selection = $Word.Selection
$Range = $Selection.Range
#Add table of content
$Toc = $Document.TablesOfContents.Add($range)

#Create sample headers (Office language must be US or EN(?))
CreateParagraph $Selection 1
$Selection.Style = 'Heading 1'
$Selection.TypeText("Hello")
CreateParagraph $Selection 1
$Selection.Style = "Heading 2"
$Selection.TypeText("Report compiled at $(Get-Date).")
CreateParagraph $Selection 1
$Selection.Style = 'Heading 2'
$Selection.TypeText("Report compiled at $(Get-Date).")
CreateParagraph $Selection 1
$Selection.Style = 'Heading 2'
$Selection.TypeText("Report compiled at $(Get-Date).")
CreateParagraph $Selection 1
$Selection.Style = 'Heading 2'
$Selection.TypeText("Report compiled at $(Get-Date).")
CreateParagraph $Selection 1
$Selection.Style = 'Heading 2'
$Selection.TypeText("Report compiled at $(Get-Date).")

$Paragraphs = $Document.Range().Paragraphs

#create numbered lists.
NumberParagraphs $Selection $Paragraphs 2 2 1
NumberParagraphs $Selection $Paragraphs 3 3 2
NumberParagraphs $Selection $Paragraphs 4 5 -1
NumberParagraphs $Selection $Paragraphs 6 7 2

#Refresh table of content
$toc.Update()
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with Powershell, but if it will let you use everything in the object model does the example in the language reference help you? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/word-vba/articles/list-applylisttemplate-method-word?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396 Note that it's dangerous to use these because the order of the Gallery may not be the same from PC to PC, but better than what you have, perhaps...

Comment: It'd be super helpful if you included the script and a sample file (or something). Otherwise, I have to create all that stuff to test your scenario, and that's more effort than I really want to spend.

Comment: I'm sad to admit that I lack the understanding to translate these nuances from VB to Powershell. In C# I would add a reference and from there create a new ListGalleryType, but I can't seem to find the right context in Powershell..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After spending most of the day questioning my own sanity, I decided to go basically reverse engineer my own actions. Obviously one would expect that the $word object would contain all references required, which it does. I tested this earlier myself; It does contain the full range of templates under galleries. I had seen that before.

So I went back, revisiting what I had already attempted and what I had not and it turns out I had somehow ignored one obvious answer:

```
$paragraphs[0].Item($i).range.ListFormat.ApplyListTemplate($Word.ListGalleries::ListTemplates[15])
```

Now the only thing that might be an issue, is when, as Cindy says, the order or count of templates differentiates from one to the other workstation. I might have to build a solution for that, but that's of later concern.

Answer (score 0):

You have a working Powershell script that automated Word. You'd like to use the following snippet in that script:

```
$paragraphs[0].Item($i).range.ListFormat.ApplyListTemplate('wdStyleListBullet2')
```

But, you can't quite get it to work?

I cooked up the following:

```
$word = New-Object -ComObject word.application
$word.Visible = $false
$doc = $word.documents.add()
$doc.paragraphs.add()
$template = $word.ListGalleries[[Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdListGalleryType]::WdBuiltinStyle].ListTemplates(2)
$doc.paragraphs(1).range.ListFormat.ApplyListTemplate($template)
```

It's kind of what you want. I just don't know parameter to provide to `ListTemplates()`. It takes a number. I'm not sure which number ties to 'wdStyleListBullet2'. You have to figure that out. Unfortunately, ComObject's don't provide the same reflective abilities as .NET objects. :-(

But, to your question, that's how you'd call the `ApplyListTemplate()` function.

Comment: Hey Adam, I have edited my original post to contain most of the code I currently have. I've cleared some comments to make it more readable. 

I've added the specific part of your code to mine, but sadly it seems $template ends up $null.

I've then copied your code directly to a new ps1 file, but again, it fails, though that seems to be related to the call to paragraphs.

The irony is that I had some parts of the code you wrote, but, as in your example, couldn't resolve it to anything with an actual value. Maybe you can figure it out with the whole script.

Comment: Actually, is it possible that the numbering under the listtemplates is not in order of appearance (0, 1, 2, etc) like in an array, but rather based on explicitly assigned numbers, like say...2030?